# Segmentation Fault caused by redefined operator '='

Tags: c++, c++17

I compiled this program by g++ and clang++.
G++ executable print one "trigger A copy assignment".
Clang++ executable print two "trigger A copy assignment" and has a segmentation fault.
Does there has any ill-formed? Or is it only clang's problem?

version: gcc-7.4.0/clang-10.0.0

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
  A &operator =(const A &other) {
    std::cout << "trigger A copy assignment\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  A x,y;
  y = x;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `return *this;` to your operator implementation - does it give the same errors?

Comment: Did you compile with `-Wall`? I get `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` when I do.

Comment: @ tadman I see the warning. Sorry, raise the unrealistic question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While not *formally* ill-formed, your code *does* create **undefined behaviour**, as your assignment operator function, declared as returning an `A&`, doesn't actually return anything!

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return):

> Flowing off the end of a value-returning function (except main)
>   without a return statement is undefined behavior.

This minor code amendment will prevent the `clang` crash (but maybe won't do what you want):

```cpp
struct A {
    A& operator =(const A& other) {
        std::cout << "trigger A copy assignment\n";
        return *this; // MUST return SOMETHING!
    }
};
```

Comment: The result of the expression is not assigned to y - that's the job *of* the expression, which in this case does nothing.

Comment: Yes, the code is weird. But it is g++ testsuite (g++.dg/other/copy2.C). I have a work about it...

Comment: @eddiekuo I have updated (improved?) the answer: The fact that the programs built by `g++` and `clang` behave differently reflects the very nature of *undefined* behaviour.

Comment: It is surprising clang and gcc wouldn't treat this as a compilation error by default though.

Comment: @Rollie I guess there's undefined behaviour in both the generated code *and* the compilers! (`MSVC` gives an error.)

Comment: @Rollie it's only undefined if execution passes the return point, so a conforming compiler has to prove that execution reaches there in order to give an error message

Comment: @M.M Is it dictated the compiler must accept code in this case?

Comment: @Rollie my previous comment answers that